# How to create a map-based survey with drag-drop capability?

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, geolocation, arcgis-survey123, drag-and-drop

I am an urban planning master student. I need to create a map-based survey for my research. The survey should allow users to drag some different points from the toolbar to the map showing next to it. When a user finishes the survey coordinate data and types of the dragged points should be store. To make it clear i would like to collect data of the parks which people think it is safe, fun, better etc. To allow people to rate these parks and collect geolocated data using point generation seems logical. Here is a good example for this kind of survey, http://mydowntown.sasaki.com/houston/survey.html?relation=live . Using map API's like MapBox, Google Maps, or libraries like leaflet etc. is the most suitable way i suppose. I also have access to ArcGIS products, which are quite efficient when it comes to surveying. However my coding knowledge is like zero and im having hard time while scripting this kind of interaction without any basic example tutorial.

So how do i create a survey like above? Is there any pre-made applications for it, or ant examples that i can tweak?

Comment: You might want to narrow it down a little, if I was doing thisd using open-source, I'd use Leaflet with the Drw tools, and a sidebar, then using Node or PHP write webservices/REST code to populate a Postgesql/PostGIS database on a web server. Esri, you would need the JS API, ArcServer FeatureLayers, and a SDE database in the backend. You might want some logic so people don't play and populate your database with garbage.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will just focus on creating 5 different draggable raiting markers with some pre-defined attributes. When they are dropped on the map leaflet will draw a point with same attributes hopefully. And i decided to collect data as geojson(or even a standart table) rather than spending time with esri stuff. I can use geojson if i require a shapefile later.  Thinking this way can you go a little bit detail in the workflow, if its ok? I can figure out the draw tools maybe but is there a way to collect drawn data via scripting?

Comment: Here is a link to a teaching project I did. Using Leaflet, PHP, and MySQL, it was just points based, so I just used  X & Y fields, and the points are served back as GeoJSON. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/phpDemo/ If you were going to use polygons and lines PostGIS would be better then mySQL.

Comment: Wow thanks for the support,I think that is more than enough for my research. I just need to get my head around coding. :D